# Connect to RDS inside a VPC using Opsworks located in another VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-vpc, opsworks

I have a RDS instance (mysql) inside a VPC called vpc-a (10.0.0.0/16). This instance is private, it can only be accessed from vpc-a.

We created a stack on opsworks inside another VPC called vpc-b (10.1.0.0). We want to connect opsworks to the RDS but it doesn't work. It refuses to connect. I tried adding said subnet to the RDS security group. Also read a lot of documentation but I haven't stumbled across the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

VPCs are isolated from each other, even within the same AWS account, and cannot, by default, exchange traffic.  Nothing you do in security groups changes this; however, within the same AWS region, VPCs can be peered, and it sounds like this is what you will need.

> A VPC peering connection is a networking connection between two VPCs that enables you to route traffic between them using private IP addresses.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html